# Why can not I group a report in access based on WeekDay?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a table that I created a sql from it. The sql is as follow:

```
SELECT MainTable.Person1ID,  WeekdayName(Weekday([CalanderDate]),False,2) AS WeekDay, MainTable.SesssionType, MainTable.CalanderDate
FROM MainTable;
```

I can generate a normal report from this query, but if I group the report based on weekday, it generate an error:

```
Data mismatched in criteria expression.
```

If I try to group based on `CalanderDate` then it works as long as I am not putting weekday on group header.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

I am using Access 2003.

Comment: Try wrapping the name of the WeekDay field in brackets like `WeekdayName(Weekday([CalanderDate]),False,2) AS [WeekDay]`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Weekday([CalendarDate])` as grouping clause.